# How to get list of class instances from file using pickle

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pickle

I have 2 classes: Group and student. I create list with different groups, each group has property that contains list of students. Then I save it in file using pickle in this way:

```
tfile = open( 'test', "w" )
pickle.dump(encodedList, tfile)
tfile.close()
```

These 3 lines work well. After launching the program again I want to get all this information from file in list, I do it according to many tutorials like this:

```
encodedList = []
try:
    with open('test') as file:
        tfile = open( 'test', "r" )
        encodedList = pickle.load( tfile )
except IOError:
    tfile = open( 'test', "w" )
    pickle.dump( encodedList, tfile )
tfile.close()
```

But Programm crashes here giving next errors:

[image]

I tried to read this list from file in different similar ways, but this error is always the same, could you please help me?

Comment: why are you opening once using `with` and then again inside the with block?

Comment: Also what is Group referring to,what did you pickle?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I removed second opening, but it didn't help.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Group is just name of class, then I create its instances and add them into list.

Comment: If the class definition in the same file you are doing the unpickling from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, unpickling is from the very beginning, to make my list visible later, then I have my class definition. I'm new in python, maybe it's not very good style.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You saved me! Thank you a lot, really, I had to define all my classes firstly and then unpickle them, I have to study harder:)

Comment: No worries, as mentioned in my answer, if you are unpickling from another file make sure you have `from my_py import Group` etc.. before you try to unpickle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class definition must come before you unpickle:

```
class foo(): # works
    pass
encodedList = []
try:
    with open('test') as file:
        tfile = open( 'test', "r" )
        encodedList = pickle.load( tfile )
except IOError:
    tfile = open( 'test', "w" )
    pickle.dump( encodedList, tfile )
tfile.close()
```

And how it fails:

```
encodedList = []
try:
    with open('test') as file:
        tfile = open( 'test', "r" )
        encodedList = pickle.load( tfile )
except IOError:
    tfile = open( 'test', "w" )
    pickle.dump( encodedList, tfile )
tfile.close()


class foo(): # fails
    pass
```

The output will be `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'` which is what you are seeing in your own code. If the class definition is in another file, add the import before you try to unpickle

Answer (score 1):

You could try **not** using `pickle`, and instead using a better serializer, like `dill`.  With `dill` the class definition is stored with the pickle of the instance, so it's easy if you don't know what type of instance you are unpickling.

```
>>> class Student(object):
...   def __init__(self, name):
...     self.name = name
...   def __repr__(self):
.. .    return "Student(%s)" % self.name
... 
>>> class Group(list):  
...   pass
... 
>>> myclass = Group([Student('Ted'), Student('Fred'), Student('Jane')])
>>>  
>>> import dill
>>> with open('myclass.pkl', 'w') as f:
...   dill.dump(myclass, f)
... 
>>>
```

After pickling the list of instances, then quit and start a new session…

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep  2 2015, 17:36:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('myclass.pkl', 'r') as f:
...   myclass = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> myclass
[Student('Ted'), Student('Fred'), Student('Jane')]
>>> [student.name for student in myclass]
['Ted', 'Fred', 'Jane']
>>> type(myclass)
<class '__main__.Group'>
```

Note the answer above is actually storing an instance of a subclass of lists, that is storing three class instances.